# How to remount /data to external partition on sdcard

Tags: external-sd

I am trying to mount default partition from sdcard to /data (replace default).

**My situation:**

Android 4.4.2 
Colorovo Citytonre vision

**End Goal:** I want more space for apps because all storage is used by default apps after update.

```
root@colorovo_citytone_vision:/ # blkid

/dev/block/mmcblk0p27: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p28: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p31: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p32: UUID="4019-1410" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1: UUID="d646a19a-670f-491d-9170-67c8d22fb4c7" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk1p2: UUID="54AE-2B3D" TYPE="vfat"

root@colorovo_citytone_vision:/ # cat fstab.java

/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/system              /system             ext4      ro                                                   wait
/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/cache               /cache              ext4      noatime,nosuid,nodev,nomblk_io_submit,errors=panic   wait
/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/userdata            /data               ext4      rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc wait,encryptable=footer
/devices/platform/sdhci.1/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0 auto        vfat      defaults                                             noemulatedsd,nonremovable,voldmanaged=sdcard0:auto
/devices/platform/sdhci.0/mmc_host/mmc2                 auto                vfat      defaults                                             voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/devices/platform/3f120000.usb-otg/usb1                 auto                vfat      defaults                                             voldmanaged=usbdisk0:auto
/dev/block/zram0                                        none                swap      defaults                                             zramsize=201326592
```

What I've tried:

Edit fstab.java in data line

```
/dev/block/platform/sdhci.1/by-name/userdata            /data               ext4      rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc wait,encryptable=footer
```

To:

```
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1            /data               ext4      rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc wait,encryptable=footer
```

Then I mounted

```
mount -o remount -t yaffs2 /data
```

And nothing happened, when I reboot phone `fstab.java` is still as before changes.

I remount / as rw and i know that fstab.java is changed.

Comment: It's not as easy as just changing a mount point, if it was people would do this all the time, which they don't. Even apps that do something similar have to use symbolic links in the original mount point. Unfortunately I cannot assist you, but I will watch with interest if someone can.

Comment: anyone know how do this ?